# Export Import Library with Lookup column

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, export, library

I did export operation of custom library in Central Administration. Library has some custom fields and Lookup field on existing library on the site.

After exporting main library and all dependecie librarys for lookup field .. i did import using Sharepoint shell - Import-SPWeb.

New imported list does not have information in lookup fields/columns .. neather if I edit items in this library there is no connection to the library where I lookup info. This is very bad. I don't have any atention to do this manually for all 600 entrys.

Thanky you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Lists do not export the values of the lookup fields as there is no gaurentee the list will exist in the destination.  Other fields behave this way too, particularly person/group fields.

Answer (score 1):

> ***After exporting list to a new location. Look Up Columns are not
>   working  because they lost the relation among them. *Solution to this problem you need to recreate
>   the look up columns*.***

Answer (score 0):

In addition, lookup fields and person fields do not store the value, but rather the ID of the row from the original list. At the target site, even having the same list may not work, because the items may have been created in a different order, and the ID numbers will be different.

You can transport the values over via Access or Excel, though.